# How can you disable specific Material-UI DataGrid Column Menu options?

Tags: datagrid, material-ui

I know that 'disableColumnMenu' will disable the entire column, and setting 'sortable' and 'filterable' to false will remove those options for that column. Is there a way to disable specific menu options, or otherwise modify the column menu? I want to keep the columns sortable and filterable, but remove the 'show' and 'hide' options.

[image]

Answer (score 8):

To remove the "Show"-columns and "Hide" menu items from the column menu, I just added the `disableColumnSelector` to the DataGrid Component as show in the code image below.

[image: remove-show-hide-from-menu]

[image: disableColumnSelector_code]

Comment: This option `disableColumnSelector` removes only the `showColumn` option, but not the `hide` option.
How can the `hide` option be removed?

Comment: @Nemanja Milosavljevic : I'm able to remove both items from the menu.  Can you post code or something that allows me to see what you are seeing?

Comment: @NemanjaMilosavljevic column hide property is now deprecated
 https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/column-visibility/#column-hide-property-deprecated

Answer (score 8):

You can do this by creating a custom menu and only including the filter and sort menu options.

```js
// Assuming other imports such as React...

import {
    GridColumnMenuContainer, 
    GridFilterMenuItem, 
    SortGridMenuItems
} from '@material-ui/data-grid';

const CustomColumnMenu = (props) => {
    const { hideMenu, currentColumn } = props;
    return (
        <GridColumnMenuContainer
            hideMenu={hideMenu}
            currentColumn={currentColumn} 
            {...props}
        >
            <SortGridMenuItems onClick={hideMenu} column={currentColumn} />
            <GridFilterMenuItem onClick={hideMenu} column={currentColumn} />
        </GridColumnMenuContainer>
    );
};

export default CustomColumnMenu;
```

Then, use it in your grid like so:

```js
// Assuming imports are done including DataGrid, CustomColumnMenu, and React...
                    <DataGrid
                        // Assuming: rows, rowHeight, etc...
                        components={{
                            ColumnMenu: CustomColumnMenu
                        }}
                    />
```

[image: Result of using the outlined Custom Column Menu]

Comment: After implementing this, if I clicked on the menu button, it worked as expected and displayed only the items I wanted.  However, I would receive an error in my console:

Failed prop type: The prop `open` is marked as required in `ForwardRef(GridColumnMenuContainer)`, but its value is `undefined`.

After much experimentation I fixed it by adding {...props} to the component like this:

<GridColumnMenuContainer
      {...props}
      hideMenu={hideMenu}
      currentColumn={currentColumn}>

Thanks Neil! With my small edit, your solution works great.

Comment: your response is deprecated as the API changed.

Answer (score 3):

There is also a prop **disableColumnSelector={true}** (passed to DataGrid component), however it will disable column selection for all columns, not only 1 specific column header.

Comment: How do we remove specific column from the Show/Hide Columns menu?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using the `hideable` field in the columns definitions.

```
const columns: Array<GridColDef> = [
  {
    field: 'foo',
    hideable: false
  },
  // ... other cols 
]

<DataGrid columns={columns} rows={rows} />
```